# About websites login & logout with facebook SDK in php

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I am the new in Facebook SDK.
my Websites login with facebook account but there's trouble

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    require_once '../FacebookAPI/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
      'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
      ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
        echo 'No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.';
        exit;
    }

    // Logged in
    echo '<h3>Signed Request</h3>';
    var_dump($helper->getSignedRequest());

    echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
?>
```

Why it shows out "No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet."
Did I miss something ? I think $accessToken is NULL But why?

Comment: well, did you implement facebook login?

Comment: btw, you should try with the js sdk first, if you are new to the facebook api. it´s a LOT easier to handle: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://myWebsites/back.php', $permissions);
 echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

I put the code in there, it could login, but accessToken still null
should I put js sdk first really?

Comment: at least try it. i am not sure why people go the hard road with php, while it´s so much easier with javascript. also, no redirection needed.

Comment: I solved the Problem...Thanks bro...

Comment: this is my test sites, all program with php SDK no js
(http://www.hyh.clhyc.tw/FacebookSDK/loginFB.php)